# In a complete lattice every monotone function has a fixpoint (Knaster–Tarski Theorem)

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, fixed-point-theorems

L is a complete lattice, so every subset has a supremum and infimum. In addition, there exists a function $f:L \rightarrow L$ such that $a \leq b$ implies $f(a) \leq f(b)$. Prove that there exists some $k$ in L such that $f(k) = k $

I started by taking the set $S = \{a | f(a) \geq a\}$, but I am now stuck on this.

Comment: Hi, parr; you can use \geq for >=, and \leq for <= ; I just edited, hope it's O.K .

Comment: oh great thanks for the infos

Answer (score 11):

This is called the [Knaster-Tarski Fixpoint Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).

Define $A:=\{x\in L\colon x\leq f(x)\}$.

Since $L$ is a complete lattice you can define $\alpha :=\bigvee _LA$.

By definition $\alpha \in L$ so it makes sense to consider $f(\alpha)$.

Note that $A\neq \varnothing$, (why?).

Let's prove that $f(\alpha)$ is an upperbound of $A$. Let $x\in A$. Since $f$ is order-preserving (or monotone), then $f(x)\leq f(\alpha)$. On the other hand, by definition of $A$ it also holds that $x\leq f(x)$, therefore $x\leq f(\alpha)$. 
Since $x$ was arbitrary it was proven that $f(\alpha)$ in an upperbound of $A$ and therefore $\color{blue}{\alpha \leq f(\alpha)}$.

Now using this last inequality and the fact that $f$ is order-preserving yields $f(\alpha)\leq f(f(\alpha))$, therefore $f(\alpha)\in A$, thus $\color{blue}{f(\alpha)\leq\alpha}$.

Hence $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

---

You should emulate the proof by using meet instead of join. Consider the set $B=\{x\in L\colon f(x)\leq x\}$.

Comment: you said "f(α) in an upperbound of A and therefore α≤f(α)". Why is this true? It is not necessary that the upper bound of a set be a member of the set right? So I don't follow why your statement is true. Any help?

Comment: @parr1rt4 What is $\alpha$?

Comment: α is the sup of A right?

Comment: Yes, now what is the definition of supremum of a set?

Comment: the supremum of a subset S of a poset T is the least element of T greater than or equal to all s in S.

Comment: Yes, it is the smallest of the upperbounds. Since $f(\alpha)$ is an upperbound ... ?

Comment: i dont understand at all

Comment: @parr1rt4 Ok, let's see. You agree that $\alpha$ is an upperbound of $A$, right? Do you also agree that $f(\alpha)$ is an upperbound of $A$?

Comment: yes i agree with both of those

Comment: Now, by definition $\alpha$ is the smallest upperbound of $A$, which means that given an upperbound $u$, we'll have $\alpha \leq u$. Do you agree?

Comment: ah i see now. of course. that makes perfect sense, thanks and apologies

Comment: @parr1rt4 Do not apologize. No problem.

Comment: "Note that A≠∅A≠∅, (why?)." Does this statement follow from the fact that $x = \inf{L}$ must be in A?

Comment: @jesterII Exactly. The entity $\inf(L)$ exists because $L$ is a complete lattice. And obviously $\inf(L)\leq f\left(\inf(L)\right)$, hence $\inf(L)\in A$.